# iphone open new window with data from table cell touch

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In an iPhone application, I have a table view with some data inside its cells (UITextField, UITextView).  When you touch a cell I need to set those data (UITextField, UITextView) to a textfield and textView which is in another view and open that view.

Using this code, it opens new view on touch event on a cell but it didn't load the data 
as I expect from these lines:

```
[obsevationListView setTitle:titletxt];
[obsevationListView setTxtView:titletxt];
```

Hope someone can help me with a simple example.
Thanks...

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  //  NSIndexPath *aIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
  //  return aIndex; //return nil so the cell is not selected

  NSLog(@"cell is selected %d >> %d",(int)indexPath, indexPath.row);
  Observation *observer = (Observation *)[observations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSLog((NSString *)observer.title);
  ObsevationListView *obsevationListView = [[ObservationViewControllor alloc] 
                      initWithNibName:@"ObservationViewControllor" 
                      bundle:nil];
  NSString *titletxt = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", observer.title];

  [obsevationListView setTitle:titletxt];
  [obsevationListView setTxtView:titletxt];

  //    UITextView *textView;
  //    UITextField *messageTitle;

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:obsevationListView animated:YES];

  return  indexPath;
}
```

I used didSelectRowatIndexPath method but it didn't work  actually i need to open new view with loading some details 
example: I show a list of draft observations in a table view when I click on a row, I want to load that observation drafts to the fields of a edit view but I use this same window to make new observations with empty fields.
should I use if conditions in init method of the edit view ??? someone please guide me In java I can do it using overloaded constructors How do I suppose to do it in Iphone apps ??

Answer (score 0):

use

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

instead of

```
willSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Dill is delicious... but I believe you mean `did`.